# Deny remote access to ASP.net resource

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have ASP.NET WebService as a part of ASP.NET application. However, some of its methods are not supposed to be invoked directly from browser, they are just accessed by winservice from within the same local network. Is there any way to protect web service from remote access by means of web.config files or IIS configuration with no firewall configuration involved?

Comment: I believe an AOP library will help you.

Comment: Thanks, than can help probably, but in my circumstances that seems to be a little bit of overengineering, as we don't use AOP libs in our project.

Answer (score 0):

Change ACLs on your "non accessable" resources so that IIS_USER has no rights. Create another website that binds to localhost:80. Create a new user account and set that as the login account for the new website. Grant that user read/execute to the files you're trying to obscure.